# using class functions to display a list

Tags: c++, class, linked-list

I am trying to make a to do list program .I am  trying to print my to do list tasks, then print out options for the user.the problem is that after using the list class function ".display()" what comes after it is ignored. Also the first node I create doesn't count when I try to print the list.

this is main.cpp .

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include "node.h"

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    list m;
    m.createnode(0, 0, 0, "", "");

    m.createnode(1, 1, 1, "j", "j");
    m.createnode(1, 1, 1, "j", "j");
    m.display();


    cout << "1.choose task";




    return 0;
}
```

this is node.h (the list class)

```
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;
typedef struct node {

    std::string name;
    std::string task;
    int due_date[3];
    bool done;
    node*next;
}m;
class list
{
private:
    node head ,tail;
public:
    list()
    {
        head = NULL;
        tail = NULL;
    }
    void createnode(int d, int m, int y, std::string task, std::string name)
    {
        node *temp = new node;
        temp->due_date[0] = d;
        temp->due_date[1] = m;
        temp->due_date[2] = y;
        temp->task = task;
        temp->name = name;
        temp->done = false;

        temp->next = NULL;
        if (head == NULL)
        {
            head = temp;
            tail = temp;
            temp = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            tail->next = temp;
            tail = temp;
        }
    }

    void display()
    {
        node *temp = new node;
        temp = head;
        tail = NULL;
            while (temp != NULL)
            {
                temp = temp->next;

                cout << temp->name << "\n";
                cout << temp->due_date[0] << "/" << temp->due_date[1] << "/" << temp->due_date[2] << "\n";
                cout << "description: ";
                cout << temp->task << "\n";
                cout << "status: ";
                if (temp->done == false)
                {
                    cout << "incomplete"<<"\n";

                }
                else {
                    cout << "complete"<<"\n";

                }

                cout << "";
            }


    }
};
```

Comment: Why are you prefixing the member function calls with the class name? It’s unnecessary and very unconventional.

Comment: Look at this code `node *temp = new node;
        temp = head;`. You assign something to `temp`, then on the very next line you assign something different to `temp`. Didn't that strike you as odd? Obviously it should be just `node *temp = head;`.

Answer (score 1):

This function definition

```
    void display()
    {
        node *temp = new node;
        temp = head;
        tail = NULL;
            while (temp != NULL)
            {
                temp = temp->next;

                cout << temp->name << "\n";
                cout << temp->due_date[0] << "/" << temp->due_date[1] << "/" << temp->due_date[2] << "\n";
                cout << "description: ";
                cout << temp->task << "\n";
                cout << "status: ";
                if (temp->done == false)
                {
                    cout << "incomplete"<<"\n";

                }
                else {
                    cout << "complete"<<"\n";

                }

                cout << "";
            }


    }
};
```

Does not make sense.

Firstly there is a memory leak

```
        node *temp = new node;
        temp = head;
```

because at first memory is allocated and its address is assigned to the variable `temp` and then the variable `temp` is reassigned.

This statement

```
        tail = NULL;
```

is entirely unclear. The value of `tail` is set to `NULL`.

In the while loop

```
            while (temp != NULL)
            {
                temp = temp->next;
                //...
```

1. the first node is skipped and 2) there can be undefined behavior then `temp->next` is equal to `NULL`.

The function can be defined the following way

```
    std::ostream & display( std::ostream &os = std::cout ) const
    {
        for  ( node *current = head;  current != nullptr; current = current->next )
        {
            os << current->name << '\n';
            os << current->due_date[0] << "/" << current->due_date[1] << "/" << current->due_date[2] << '\n';
            os << "description: ";
            os << current->task << '\n';
            os << "status: ";
            if ( current->done == false)
            {
                os << "incomplete" << '\n';
            }
            else {
                os << "complete" << '\n';
            }

            os << '\n';
        }

        return os;
   }
```